# In SVG, what's the difference between using <symbol> versus using an object defined in <defs>?

Tags: svg

In SVG, a re-usable graphical object can be defined using <symbol> and referenced using <use>, but the same thing can be achieved by defining the graphical object in <defs>.

For example, the following displays two rectangles defined in these two ways. (Different positions and dimensions are used so both can be seen. Otherwise, no difference in the re-usable object.)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 500 500">

    <defs>
        <rect id="myRect" x="30" y="30" width="30" height="40" />
    </defs>
    
    <symbol id="mySymbol">
        <rect x="80" y="80" width="80" height="90" />
    </symbol>
    
    <use href="#myRect" />
    <use href="#mySymbol" />
</svg>
```

Is there any functional difference? Or any reason why one might want to (or should) use <symbol> in some situations?

Comment: probably the main advantage of `<symbol>` element is it's ability to have an individual viewBox. That's handy e.g. for creating  icon asset collections containing multiple icons with completely different boundaries. This concept is also used by many icon libs like fontAwesome, feather-icons)

Comment: @herrstrietzel Thanks. I had noticed that `<symbol>` can take a viewBox spec, but wasn't sure if that was the only or most interesting difference.